# I want to understand the execution of the following SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, correlated-subquery

```
create table student(StudentCode varchar,  Marks int);   

insert into student values ('a',100);
insert into student values ('b',100);
insert into student values ('c',100);
insert into student values ('d',90);
insert into student values ('e',90);
insert into student values ('f',80);
insert into student values ('g',70);

SELECT *
FROM student a
WHERE a.StudentCode IN (
        SELECT TOP 1 b.StudentCode
        FROM student b
        WHERE a.marks = b.marks
        );
```

The Output is

```
StudentCode Marks
1   a   100
2   d   90
3   f   80
4   g   70
```

Why each record is not repeating after joining with subquery

Answer (score 0):

For each Mark value, show me one student that has it, even if there are more students with that Mark
Remove the top and all will be repeated:

```
select * from student a where a.StudentCode in (select b.StudentCode from student b where a.marks=b.marks);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
select s.*
from student s
where s.StudentCode in (select top 1 s2.StudentCode
                        from student s2
                        where s2.marks = s.marks
                       );
```

The correlated subquery is returning exactly one row.  Hence, `in` is not needed.  The row that is returned is an *arbitrary* row for a student that has the same marks.

If there is only one students with a given `marks` value -- such as `'f'` and `'g'`, then that student matches.

For the rest, the matching student might or might not be the one reference in the outer query.  So, the subquery will filter them out.

If you remove `top (1)`, then the query will return all students.